# Attempting to use a Real-Time Heat Map w/ MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, heatmap, tweepy

First off, a little background.

My Python is around an intermediate level.
I am very new to MongoDB/Redis/Flask.

In order to answer this question effectively, I think that you'd have to be willing to take the time to understand how this heat map works from the blog writer. 
I'm using this blog's code repository: 
http://blog.comsysto.com/2012/07/10/real-time-twitter-heat-map-with-mongodb/#comment-770

Which is available at this link on Git: 
https://github.com/comsysto/twitter-realtime-heatmap

I started redis. 
In MongoDB, I've created a capped collection named tweets_tail under the database tstream. tstream.tweets_tail.isCapped() does in fact return true. 
When I run tstream.py, I've put print statements within each function in the StreamListener class. None of those functions are ever actually called when it's executed.

When I run tweet_service.py, I get the following:

> > > avon:heatmap kalil$ python tweet_service.py 
> > >       * Running on `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` 
> > >       * Restarting with reloader 
> > >       beginning to tail... 
> > >       1 
> > >       127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2012 14:57:54] "GET /tweets?callback=loomit HTTP/1.1" 200 -

It appears that in tweet_service.py, it's printing that it's on the first iteration in the pubsub.listen() function.

I don't, however, get any new tweets beyond that, because queries to the collection:

> > > db.tweets_tail.count() 
> > >       0

I suspect that it has something to do with Tweepy's notoriously broken Streaming API (as is the word in my lab), and no tweets are actually being received and saved in MongoDB. In reality, I haven't a clue.

Any help at all would be much appreciated - please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Tweepy was the culprit - make sure you have the latest version, as the new commits fixed a lot of the streaming problems.